# What's the best practice for handling bill details with Stripe?

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

In my mobile app when the user has selected some items, I would like them to be able to review their order and see a preview of their bill (the price of each item, subtotal, taxes and total). However I would not want them to pay immediately. Once they place the order, they will not be charged until the order is accepted.

Do I calculate the user's subtotal, tax and total on my server or does stripe provide an api to handle these?

I've read the docs on invoicing and checkout, and checkout seems to be the api for my situation but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "place the order" and "order is accepted". Normally when the Stripe's Checkout Session page is displayed to your customer and they push the "Pay" button, the transaction will be executed immediately (they paid), then the customer can be redirected back to your page or app.

If you want to somehow delay the payment until a specific timing (that you want to review or execute some logic, before eventually "accept" the order), you can consider using [Checkout with Setup Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=checkout).